# redirect issue in function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used a redirect url in my logout function, 1st time logout it works fine but subsequent requests after 1st time logout doesn't reaches logout function , rather it directly calls redirect url  and why is it so, 
any explanation?

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url('user/def'));
}
```

after login session works fine in other pages

```
public function login(){
    if($user->name && $pwd){
        $data = array('id'=>$user->id,'username'=> $uname,'loggedin' => TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user',$data);
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: redirect('login', 'refresh'); replace with your redirect code and check it.

Comment: no , it didn't work

Comment: actually logout works fine in localhost but not in server

Comment: clear the browser cache with Ctl+Shirt+Delete and try with redirect(base_url('login'), 'refresh');

Comment: well, tried it but problem persists. after clearing 1st time it works but later on it continues to show same problem

Comment: I supposed it was due to caching but for that purpose I used ,                        $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");                                               in the controller but still no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was definitely the caching problem but for that I cleared the browser cache and it work with charm for 1st but later on same issue
don't know whether the problem is caused by browser cache or whether codeigniter manages any cache for it
so , added header for no-cache as mentioned below :

```
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache")
```

but still didn't work

finally cleared the issue by making the logout url dynamic i.e instead of calling

```
<a href='user/logout' >logout</a>
```

the logout url is called as :

```
<a href="<?php echo 'user/logout?i='.rand(); ?>" >logout</a>
```

> www.example.com/user/logout?i=67543878

each time with a new i value the browser will treat this as new url to be called, which is how I solved the above mentioned issue.

If there is any other valid solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

i think your redirect instruction code in function logout is wrong. it should be
`redirect ('login');`

Comment: contrary to redirect ('login') ,  redirect(base_url('login')) would use full base url with subsequent uri segments as : http:www.example.com/login  whereas simple  redirect ('login') would use  login uri as redirect url appended to the current url

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
redirect('Controller_name/function_name');
```